# Number of ideals in a minimal irreducible decomposition

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Assume $R$ is a local ring, $M\subseteq R$ is the maximal ideal, $I\subseteq R$ is an $M$-primary ideal and $I=\bigcap_{i=1}^n Q_i$ is a minimal irreducible decomposition of $I$ (i.e. $Q_i\subseteq R$ are irreducible ideals and the intersection of a proper subset of $\{Q_i\}$ can not equal $I$ (minimal property)).

Using the fact that for any $i$ the (vector space) dimension of $(Q_i:M)/Q_i$ over the field $R/M$ equals $1$ (because $Q_i$ are irreducible) I would like to prove that the dimension of $(I:M)/I$ over $R/M$ equals $n$. I ask (for a hint) for a proof of this fact.

My initial idea was to build a composition series of length $n$ from $I$ to $(I:M)$ but I failed to find the suitable ideals between $I$ and $(I:M)$.

Comment: By the way, the original proof is by Emmy Noether in "Idealtheorie in Ringbereichen" Math. Ann. (1921) 83: 24. doi:10.1007/BF01464225 It is in German but that aside it is quite readable (if one accepts that she speaks about ideals is if they were numbers, so she says that one ideal divides an ideal for containment in the other direction etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is proved in Section 3 of *Computational methods in commutative algebra and algebraic geometry* by W. V. Vasconcelos.  From the 1998 edition of the book:

**Proposition 3.1.7**. Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a local commutative Noetherian ring. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be an associated prime of an $R$-module $M$ and denote $\Delta_\mathfrak{p}(M)$ the submodule of $M$ whose elements are annihilated by $\mathfrak{p}$. The number of irreducible $\mathfrak{p}$-primary components in an irredundant irreducible decomposition of $0\subset M$ is $\dim_{k(\mathfrak{p})}(\Delta_\mathfrak{p}(M))_\mathfrak{p}$.

Your question is the case where $M=R/I$.

The main idea of the proof is to analyze what happens to the socle $\Delta_\mathfrak{p}(M)$ under the map $M \to \bigoplus_i M/M_i$ which is at least injective if $0 = \bigcap M_i$ is any decomposition of zero.

N.b. In the second edition of the book the numbering changed.  I think it is Prop. 3.15 there, but I'm not sure.

A related question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310709/is-an-irreducible-ideal-in-r-irreducible-in-rx).