# Is an irreducible ideal in $R$ irreducible in $R[x]$?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring and $I\subset R$ an ideal that is irreducible in the sense that if $I = J_1 \cap J_2$, then $I=J_1$ or $I=J_2$. Is (the ideal generated by) $I$ irreducible in the polynomial ring $R[x]$?

The answer to the question is "yes" since the number of irreducible components has a homological characterization which goes roughly as follows: Localize at the associated prime $P$ of $I$.  The minimal number of irreducible intersectands of $I$ equals the $R_{P}/P_P$-vector space dimension of the socle of $R[x]_{P}/I_{P}$. Now when adjoining indeterminates only the field $R[x]_P/PR[x]_P$ should grow, but the dimension is the same. This is explained in Section 3 of *Computational methods in commutative algebra and algebraic geometry* by W. V. Vasconcelos. I could post more details once I find my copy of the book.

Now the real question is: Is there a simpler proof (say without localization) or do we have to use homological invariants of ideal decompositions?

Comment: If it were reducible in $R[x]$ then by considering the constant terms don't we get a reduction in $R$?

Comment: Constant terms of what?  Generators of $IR[x]$? Please explain more.

Comment: Yes I was just thinking everything in $R[x]$ is a polynomial, and if you have an ideal in $R[x]$ doesn't $I\cap R$, where $R$ is identified with the constant polynomials in $R[x]$, give you an ideal in $R$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant What is an obstacle in this approach is that one does not know that if $J \subseteq R[x]$ is an ideal, then $J=(J\cap R)R[x]$: For example, if $R=k$ a field, then given any proper ideal $J \subseteq k[x]$, one has $J \cap k=0$, so one loses the information what $J$ was to begin with. Thus, it can theoretically happen that $IR[x]=J_1 \cap J_2$ nontrivially in $R[x]$, but, for example, $J_1\cap R=I$.

Comment: There is an answer to this question on mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/215768/is-an-irreducible-ideal-in-r-also-irreducible-in-rx